# How to handle network calls errors when the app is minimized and resumed- windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am submitting a form from my app, it has some text and some images. So while submitting the form a series of network calls will be made to upload the images(I am using httpclient library).

Now how to handle it when the user minimize the app and the network call is still in progress?

I tried to handle using using the typical try catch mechanism, but I am not able to get the Stream object, since the stream object is disposed when the app is minimized. And also I am getting UnAuthorised Exception when tried to read the image using the file path.

Tried with the BackgroundWorker but still no luck.

The ultimate thing that I want to achieve is, I want to continue the network calls when the resumes from the minimized state.

Any help or suggestion will be more helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Deactivated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.deactivated(v=vs.105).aspx) event is raised when the user minimizes your app.  You will want to handle this event, shutting down any network calls gracefully, and persisting any state data to the isolated storage.  The phone OS allows your application 10 seconds, so this will have to be enough time to either allow the pending network calls to complete, or to discard them.

Note that, after your app has been deactivated (minimized), it may or may not be preserved the next time it is launched.  You have to handle the `Activated` event, and check [`IsApplicationInstancePreserved`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.shell.activatedeventargs.isapplicationinstancepreserved(v=vs.105).aspx) -- if it is preserved, then your page and view models should be intact, otherwise you will need to restore their state from your isolated storage.

Take a look at ["App activation and deactivation for Windows Phone 8"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff817008(v=vs.105).aspx) for more info on the deactivate/activate life-cycle.

[image: Activation life-cycle]

Also, I'm not sure if you are aware of [background agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx), which can run even when your app is not.  This might be something to consider, although it might be more trouble than it is worth trying to synchronize the background agent with the app itself.